# PhpStorm adding $PROJECT_DIR$ as Include Path

Tags: phpstorm

From time to time, PhpStorm, by itself, is adding my whole project as include path in ".idea/php.xml" file. So, it is creating this entry:

```xml
<path value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
```

inside of:

```xml
<project version="4">
  <component name="PhpIncludePathManager">
    <include_path>
```

I can't determine which exact behavior is causing it. Sometimes it occurs on branch change. I've created this question to somehow ask whether someone else is having (or had) this issue. Maybe someone knows the cause and a solution on how to stop this.

Also, what is generating the whole `<include_path>` content in "php.xml" file?

Comment: *"Also, what is generating the whole `<include_path>` content in "php.xml" file?"* Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP --> Include paths. P.S. These entries can be auto-populated if "PHP | Composer | Add packages as libraries" option is enabled

Comment: @LazyOne Still, I assume, that this option should not add the whole project as Include Path?

Comment: It does not do this for me in my projects (Laravel based mostly). Must be specific to your setup I guess... but nothing concrete comes into my mind right now.